# How to make individual generated input fields for each serial number and store it on the database

Tags: php, laravel

[when you input a number in the quantity, thats the number of generated input fields[][1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ECVh.png)

Comment: Please be more clear when asking and show current code rather than just an image.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged this with laravel, I’ll assume you’re using blade.
With blade it is easy to loop a number of times. See here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#loops.
The form element will be created inside the loop with dynamic id/placeholder based on the number in the loop or other session/view variables.